# Python Different Math Calculation Results

Tags: python, math

I'm working on a school assignment and I needed to compute `math.asin(0.5773)` which gave me the result of `-0.6155406175370253` which is what I expected. However, my calculator and matlab show that the result is in fact `-0.6154181430782466`. The difference might not be to much but for my assignment things need to be very precise.

I thought it was just python but I used an online interpreter and go the same correct answer as the calculator and matlab so it looks like it's just the python installed on my computer. Is there a reason for this to happen and can there be a fix?

Python Version: 3.11.1
OS: Windows, 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: Python 3.10 I get: `math.asin(0.5773) = 0.6154181430782466`. Are you calculating it manually?

Comment: Since you think it's the specific version of python installed on your computer, please tell us what that version is! It could be that you're using a 32-bit version of python

Comment: I calculated it manually with a calculator and matlab as well (which gives your answer, the correct one). @JohnnyMopp

Sorry about that @PranavHosangadi! I edited the question. the python version is 3.11.1

Comment: We need to know which OS you're running,, and from where you got your Python. No version of CPython computes `asin()` itself, instead Python passes on whatever the platform C math library says the result is. So the question is _really_ about which version of C is in use. Python is just the messenger here ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters my os is: Windows, 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor. I downloaded Python from the official python website. I'm not sure how to check what version of C I'm using

Comment: The value `-0.6155406175370253` is exactly what you'd expect to get for `math.asin(-0.5774)`. Maybe double-check that the input to `math.asin` is what you think it is?

Comment: In that case we're using the math library supplied by Microsoft's Visual Studio (which is used to build the CPython that python.org distributes for Windows). However, I tried the same thing on the 3.11.1 Python for Win64, which was installed via the python.org installer, and got 0.6154181430782466. Was the leading minus sign really there. or is that repeated typo in your question? Or did you make a mistake and use a minus sign on the _argument_ in some cases but not others?

Comment: @TimPeters The minus sign came from a -1 that is multiplied to the asin() calculation. My question is more about the magnitude than the sign. I apologize is that caused any confusion

Comment: @MarkDickinson I realized that I indexed a matrix wrong and it just so happens that the number is 0.5774 and not 0.5773 causing that small difference. I apologize for any inconvinience

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for helping me!! I was doing matrix math and realized I actually indexed the number right next to 0.5773 which happened to be 0.5774. This was causing that very small error and it took me a bit to see that mistake. Thank you for the help!